# How to disable a button/axis on a gamepad/joystick in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, joystick, gamepad

In Windows 98/XP/Vista/7, how do I disable a joystick button/axis?

I am using a PlayStation 1 gamepad connected to my PC using a USB adapter. The problem is that the gamepad is missing the dual analog sticks, and when I press the other buttons, the gamepad sends phantom signals supposedly coming from the missing Z axis.

In Windows the gamepad is detected as a 4 axis 16 button joystick. It is also considered a "HID-compliant game controller".

Is there a way to edit the driver or registry to eliminate the phantom input?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, button configurations are stored in the game that is using the controller. The Windows drivers can be calibrated to determine the range of motion for analog actions, but it cannot remap what each button does.

Check the game's options and see if you can find a reference to the analog sticks in the controller settings, then remove the key mapping for it. The actual removal is different depending on the game, but some simply require you to select the action it is bound to and then hit cancel or remove. If you can't find it, reply back with the game title and maybe we can help more.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. But I am unable to configure the controller correctly in the game because when I press a button, the phantom axis button event is also fired. For instance, when I press the X button on the PSX controller, the missing Z-axis is also triggered. This happens in all games, so I need a fixed driver.